# STM32F4 HAL Library Button Interrupt

Tags: arm, interrupts, stm32f4, stm32cubemx, gpio-external-interrupt

I'm trying to toggle built in LED with external interrupt instead of `while` loop. Probably I'm doing something wrong with EXTI functions. Can you help me to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"


void SystemClock_Config(void);

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback (uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_0) 
    {
HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_12);
HAL_Delay(100);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);
  }
}

void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
  {
  /* EXTI line interrupt detected */
  if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_PIN_0) != RESET)
  {
    __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_0);
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(GPIO_PIN_0);
  }
}
}





void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    HAL_IncTick();
}



int main(void)
{
  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the 
Systick. */
  HAL_Init();


  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
        __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitLED;
GPIO_InitLED.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12;
GPIO_InitLED.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
GPIO_InitLED.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitLED.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitLED);

GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitButton;
GPIO_InitButton.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
GPIO_InitButton.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
GPIO_InitButton.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
GPIO_InitButton.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitButton);


HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_IRQn, 3, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);

HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0); 

}





static void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
/* Enable HSE Oscillator and activate PLL with HSE as source */
RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 25;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 336;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 7;
HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct);
/* Select PLL as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2 
clocks
dividers */
RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK |
RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5); }
```

Comment: Complete process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40061542/3820025

Comment: I don't use HAL or STM32CubeMx generated code, but isn't there supposed to be a loop in main()?

Answer (score 2):

@Bence
I checked MXCube generated code and it solved the problem much easier. 
It does not require the "callback" function, only "handler".

@Tut
Yes you're right. It requires a loop in main code.

Changes in my code:

1)

```
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback (uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
```

Deleted

2)

```
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
```

Changed to

```
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_IRQn 0 */
    if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_0)) HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD, 
GPIO_PIN_12);
  HAL_Delay(50);
    /* USER CODE END EXTI0_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN EXTI0_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END EXTI0_IRQn 1 */
```

}

3)
Added

```
while(1)
{

}
```

4)
Button pull options is changed to "GPIO_NOPULL".